# How could I show the menu page children in Wordpress Rest API?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Using Nuxtjs with Wordpress as backend and now I have the menu but if I set a new page as a child of another page it keeps showing as a menu and I see in the API: "menu_item_parent": "50" but How could I show them as a child?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please try to take more time to ask a question than one minute. This is not a chatroom. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and formulate your question in a way that it helps us understand your problem. 
I have no clue if you are having problems with getting the right data from wordpress or with rendering the data in a right way.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a request for the child pages by themselves.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=50
```